# Code::Blocks - Change color of LF at editor

Tags: code-blocks

I would like to change the color of the line feed «**LF**» character (without changing the colors of other characters) at the editor.
In particular, make it a light gray so that it is still visible but not obtrusive.

[Briefly](https://iili.io/JJgQ3Ss.md.jpg)

I will be grateful for the assistance provided.

**Note:**
I know there is an official Code::Blocks forum, but when I try to create a thread on it, this happens:

[DB Error](https://iili.io/JJgtKZl.md.jpg)

And the forum administration is in no hurry to get in touch